# How to start learning a Web Framework's structure?

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc, struts

I used some Java Web App Frameworks before like Struts, Struts2, Spring MVC and Grails. But I would like to study how do they work in principle. Like organization, caching, it's structure and stuff. You know, just to be aware of what's happening inside. Do you guys have any material or link to something like that? Really appreciate it.

Comment: All the "frameworks" are unique in their own way, there is no one answer. Pick up on framework and learn then compare.

Comment: Read their developer guide, then their API doc and sources.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html - Spring MVC has great docs on its site.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was looking for the common point between them. Or at least between a set of them. Something to get acquainted with before eating their huge source codes.

Comment: These are all MVC frameworks; first figure out MVC, then start delving into details. They're all implemented pretty differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, Vaadin you could get how it works on this page:
https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/architecture.html

Or like spring-mvc on this page:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html

Or maybe struts2 on this one:
http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/home.html

Its just find out where the architecture description is documented ;) A graph as presented on each link that is referred on this answer is really welcome to understand how they basically work.